# problema con Apache en windows 10

Tags: apache, windows10

bueno yo instale apache siguiendo una serie de instrucciones, este funciono bien, luego instale php y luego mysql, nose si el error vino luego de que volvi a usar el pc, o porque instale mysql, la cosa es que no puedo iniciar Apache.

[image: esto es el mensaje que me sale al iniciar]

este es el error que me sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The Apache service named

reported the following error: >>> 
   Invalid command 'C:Apache24Confhttpd.confLoadModule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola, usualmente es un tema de permisos aunque para estar seguro debes hacer lo que te dice el mensaje e ir a el visor de eventos de windows para ello escribes "visor de eventos" en el menu de inicio de windows y luego de que inicie vas a ir a registros de windows -> aplicación, estando intenta iniciar de nuevo el servicio y luego ves si se te agrega un nuevo mensaje de error, intenta explorar las otras listas también para ver si ves un mensaje de error que se relacione . Coloca acá los mensajes de error que dan al momento de iniciar el servicio para ayduarte. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, encontre unos mensajes de error, editare la pregunta para mostrar la captura

Comment: vale decir que habia midoficado el httpd conf, al puerto 8080 en el listen y serverName , y tambien el httpd-ssl en ves de 443 a 4433 ,haber si se arreglaba, pero sigue igual.

Comment: segui las instrucciones desde esta pagina : https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/4376-como-instalar-manualmente-apache-php-mysql-windows-10/

Comment: Bueno coloca el mensaje del detalle en la pregunta como texto, por lo que se ve al algún problema con la configuración o algún modulo tiene un problema. Coloca un archivo .conf original he intenta ejecutarlo asi a ver

Comment: ahi esta el mensaje de error, los archivos conf los deje como antes, con puerto 80 y el httpd-ssl con 443 en donde corresponde, osea como era originalmente

Comment: me salio este error tambien: AH00526: Syntax error on line 538 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:    lo curioso es que es donde agregue el modulo php, directamente copiado de la pagina que ayudaba a instalar

Comment: talvez es ese el problema, tendria que saber el texto correcto para agregarlo de manera que funcione

Comment: modifique el load module porque estaba incorrecto con la version de php, aun no me funciona, en todo caso, reiniciare el pc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo resolvi, debia cambiar las comillas que tenia por defecto el texto que copie del modulo php. Gracias por la ayuda.
 quedo asi:

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>     
    PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Comment: Perfecto :D que bueno que resolviste. Marcala como respondida. ;D